# Creating GdkPixbuf from raw data

Tags: gtk

I have some raw data in **const unsigned char*** format which is an image.

I have created GdkPixbuf by calling function gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data as under. But, when i checked the memory of new GdkPixbuf it is not created at all.

```
    virtual void onPaint(Window *wini, const unsigned char *bitmap_in, const Rect &bitmap_rect,
            size_t num_copy_rects, const Rect *copy_rects,
            int dx, int dy, const Rect &scroll_rect)
    {

        GdkPixbuf* pbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data((const guchar*)bitmap_in,GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,FALSE,8,bitmap_rect.width(),bitmap_rect.height(),GST_ROUND_UP_4(bitmap_rect.width() * 3),NULL,NULL);
        static int call_count = 0;
        string fname = "/tmp/testout/file" + toString(call_count++) + ".png";
        bool state = gdk_pixbuf_save(pbuf,fname.c_str(),"png",NULL);
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure the `rowstride` parameter is correct?

Comment: Ya dat is correct. Actaully the bitmap data is in BGR format that i need to convert into RGB and it works.